# Push Notification stopped on Live iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

My iOS app is live on the App Store and around 100 users are using this app. I have also configured push notifications in it.

Initially, Notifications ware working fine and everybody were getting the notifications But it stopped when I installed the app into one more device via Xcode.

My certificate has not expired as I have other apps attached to same certificate where it is receiving the notifications.

Can somebody tell me what can be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Development mode you can use "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com" hostname

and

in production hostname is "gateway.push.apple.com"

you can check in backend file

Comment: OK. let me check

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the certificates should be created on Production Mode : gateway.push.apple.com